# Swift different default implementations for protocol property

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols, protocol-oriented

I know that you can give a default value with a protocol extension like this

```swift
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var prop: String { get }
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    var prop: String {
        return "defaultValue"
    }
}

struct SomeA: SomeProtocol {}
struct SomeB: SomeProtocol {}

let a = SomeA()
let b = SomeB()

debugPrint(a.prop) // prints defaultValue
debugPrint(b.prop) // prints defaultValue
```

but is there a way to have different default value for different implementations of the protocol like this without implementing the property for every class or struct that conforms to this protocol?

```swift
debugPrint(a.prop) // prints defaultValue
debugPrint(b.prop) // prints differentDefaultValue
```

or some similar pattern for doing something like this?

Comment: What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: Your answer is working but I need the same implementation for lots of classes or structs and I don't want to write the same implementation again and again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol inheritance.

```swift
protocol : SomeProtocol { }

extension  {
  var prop: String { "" }
}

struct SomeA: SomeProtocol { }
struct SomeB:  { }
struct SomeC:  { }

SomeA().prop // "defaultValue"
SomeB().prop // ""
SomeC().prop // ""
```

Comment: Thank you but I know that this can be done. When I mean default value, I mean that SomeB, SomeC, SomeD gets the default value without implementing it. I'm gonna edit the question though.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to solve, but I edited it.

Comment: nice! Thanks a lot. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I was actually trying to get a different print description for a LoggerProtocol based on different classes. So now I am having a BaseLoggerProtocol and others inherit from this the description property.